# COUNT (*) gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

While Executing SQLITE with SELECT statement and having COUNT (*) to count the total number of that column, gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
It sends me the error while adding an array from one array to other. No idea why it does that but has anybody come across such issues can help around ?

```
-(void) title{

self.array = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
const char *query_stmt = "SELECT DISTINCT ID, KEY, COUNT (*)  FROM TEST GROUP BY KEY";
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        NSString *ID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(exhProduct_statement, 0)];
        NSString *KEY = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(exhProduct_statement, 1)];
        NSUInteger taskCount=  sqlite3_column_int(exhProduct_statement, 2);
        NSMutableArray *taskArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:ID, KEY, taskCount,nil] ; <--- Error

        [self.array addObject:taskArray];
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);        
}       
}
```

Comment: is that sql correct? I'd think if you want a count of distinct id-key combinations, you want to group by both key and id.

Comment: Only masochists use the SQLite C API directly in Objective-C.  [Use FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (a SQLite wrapper) or [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) (an object graph manager) instead.

Comment: Hi Dave. Thanks for tht . But I have my app ready so cant change my DB now.

Comment: it's not really *changing* your db, just making it infinitely easier to interact with (assuming you use FMDB).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `NSUInteger` into an `NSNumber`:

```
    NSMutableArray *taskArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:ID, KEY, [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:taskCount],nil] ;
```

You can later retrieve the value using

```
    NSUInteger *retrievedTaskCount = [[taskArray objectAtIndex:2] unsignedIntegerValue];
```

The reason for this is that an `NSArray` stores `NSObject`s, so any time that you have an `int`, `float`, `NSInteger`, `NSUInteger`, etc, that you wish to store in an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`, you will need to convert it into an object. `NSNumber` is a class build just for this.

Comment: Thanks PengOne. I am trying to pull the values in cellForRowAtIndexPath and how should I retrieve the value back in NSNUmber = [[taskArray objectAtIndex:2] unsignedIntValue]; is that correct ?

Comment: @lifemoveson: Not quite. Retrieve it as `NSUInteger *taskCountBack = [[taskArray objectAtIndex:2] unsignedIntValue];` The difference is that `NSNumber` is an object that serves as a containers for `int`s, `float`s, `NSInteger`s, `NSUInteger`s, etc. So if you want a value, use one of those latter 4. If you want an object (for putting it into an array, for example), then use `NSNumber`.

Comment: @Peng:Thanks a lot for the answer. But I have one more query. How do you concatenate NSUInteger with NSString ? Like in My Case NSString *key and NSUInteger taskCount?

Comment: @lifemoveson: that's a different question and probably should be asked separately. The short answer is to use `-stringWithFormat`.

Comment: @PengOne: Thanks. Its.. NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", taskCount];

Comment: @PengOne: Srry to ask you the question so late. But while accessing NSUInteger *taskCountBack = [[taskArray objectAtIndex:2] unsignedIntValue]; for value at index 2, I get 2nd array element and not the count value. Since its an array of arrays. how can I access the 2nd row count value of the array of arrays.